# Can I render an iFrame of a locally hosted html file in Quarto/RStudio?

Tags: iframe, plotly, rstudio, quarto

I have a plotly graph locally hosted at "figures/community_areas_shootings_plotly.html". I'm trying to embed this into a quarto document so its interactive when it renders. I tried this code and it seems to run but there's just a block of white space when it renders. Any fixes?

```
<iframe src="figures/community_areas_shootings_plotly.html" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>
```

I tried this code and it seems to run but there's just a block of white space when it renders. Any fixes?

```
<iframe src="figures/community_areas_shootings_plotly.html" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

````
```{=html}
<iframe src="figures/community_areas_shootings_plotly.html" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>
```
````